# Jekyll blog won't load CSS

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, jekyll, github-pages, jekyll-bootstrap

I have cloned a Jekyll Bootstrap installation with GitHub pages. Everything is working but the CSS and JavaScript aren't being loaded in the website.  It looks like a barebones HTML site.

Here is the website: https://heavensgospel.github.io/

Here is the website's files: https://github.com/heavensgospel/heavensgospel.github.io

Comment: As you discovered, a link to a website to demonstrate a problem is not of utility for future readers. Questions here should be written for future readers in mind, and should be educational/useful even after the original issue is fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently those files are missing from your file system.
Your `/assets/themes/bootstrap/css/` folder seems to contain only one file `style.css`, while other files seem to be missing. Similarly, JavaScript files too are missing.

Comment: Thank you, you fixed my problem!  You're awesome!  The person who made this bootstrap theme... they quit working on it and messed up the placement of the css and js files.  I moved them to the correct place.

Comment: The funny thing is, I ended up inlining all of the css and javascript to my default.html file because I want an awesome google pagespeed score, lol!    Thank you so much I appreciate this :)